# How do you customize exception handling behavior in JUnit 3?

Tags: java, unit-testing, exception, junit

I want to implement exception checking (like in JUnit 4) using JUnit 3. For example, I would like to be able to write tests like this:

```
public void testMyExceptionThrown() throws Exception {
    shouldThrow(MyException.class);

    doSomethingThatMightThrowMyException();
}
```

This should succeed if and only if a MyException is thrown. 
There is the ExceptionTestCase class in JUnit, but but I want something that each test* method can decide to use or not use. What is the best way to achieve this?

Answer (score 9):

Would the solution:

```
public void testMyExceptionThrown() throws Exception {
    try {
      doSomethingThatMightThrowMyException();
      fail("Expected Exception MyException");
    } catch(MyException e) {
      // do nothing, it's OK
    }
}
```

be suitable for what you're thinking of?

Also have a look at [this thread](http://www.javalobby.org/java/forums/t91320.html), where someone created a Proxy-solution for JUnit3 which seems to be another possibility to solve your problem.

Answer (score 2):

There is no need to implement your own solution because there is already one that can be used with  JUnit3 (and any other testing framework): [catch-exception](http://code.google.com/p/catch-exception/).

Answer (score 1):

The simplest approach is to use the Execute Around idiom to abstract away the try-catch that you would usually write.

More sophisticated is to note that `TestCase` is just a `Test`. I forget the details, but we can override the execution of the test (which the framework initially calls through `run(TestResult)` specified in `Test`). In that override we can place the try-catch, as per Execute Around. The `testXxx` method should call a set method to install the expected exception type.